# Heroku gets Socket Error / Timeout from NPM registry. What are good debugging steps?

Tags: heroku, owasp

I'm trying to build OWASP Juice Shop on Heroku (https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/bkimminich/juice-shop). The repo was working fine a few weeks ago, but now the heroku deploy build gives the following error output:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12 - 15
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12 - 15...
       Downloading and installing node 15.14.0...
       Using default npm version: 7.7.6

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
       npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
       npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/is-typed-array/-/is-typed-array-1.1.7.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.gYo92/_logs/2021-08-24T11_41_04_521Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
_
```

The NPM package listed definitely exists - if I put the URL into my web browser I can go straight there and download it. Is this an infrastructure problem on the Heroku side of things, something OWASP needs to fix in the juice box source (which I think hasn't changed since it was last working), or something I can try and fix somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was just a matter of waiting a few hours. For someone who encounters this question in the future, it seems to have been a Heroku infrastructure issue that eventually resolved itself.